# Create a View Controller and access labels in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have several xibs in which I have a same status bar. This status bar is composed of a View object and in it several Labels.

In the spirit of DRY, I'd like to create a UIViewController that would take care of populating this status bar, and not repeat this in each view controller.

From my limited iOS dev knowledge, I would say the best path is to create a subclass (maybe called StatusBarViewController) that inherits from UIViewController, and in the Interface Builder indicate that this view is of class StatusBarViewController.

In the StatusBarViewController code, I would override the viewDidLoad to populate the labels.

My question is, how do I get a list of all the labels from within the view controller code? Would it be better to create the labels from code or from the IB? (which would be basically just copy/pasting from one xib to all the rest).

Am I missing anything from this approach? Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to get all the labels which are placed in view controller right..then you can use for loop and chnage the values of the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both previous answers are correct but somewhat incomplete. They did guide me in the right direction. What I did finally was:

1. From what I read, it's easier to create a separate xib file for this view (for the rest I'm using the storyboard).
2. Create a subclass that extends UIView (in my case PrefsBarView), and in the interface builder assign this class to the UIView.
3. In the parent view, do the following:

(the xibs name is PrefsBar)

```
PrefsBarView *prefsBarView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PrefsBar" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[prefsBarView populatePrefsBar];
```

In this case, the populatePrefsBar is a method I created to populate the prefs status.

```
prefsBarView.frame = CGRectMake(
    self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width - prefsBarView.frame.size.width,
    self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height - prefsBarView.frame.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,
    prefsBarView.frame.size.width, prefsBarView.frame.size.height );
[_myMainView addSubview:prefsBarView];
```

The steps above are used to make sure the view is placed at the bottom of the visible area. You have to take into consideration the status bar size (on the very top of the screen) and the navigation bar size (if you're using one). Also you shouldn't hard code a value... It probably won't work in retina displays.

An ideal situation would be for all the resizing occur inside the PrefsBarView, however according to Apple docs you shouldn't access the parent view's nav controller (or so I understood), so this is repeated in all the view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try in your case is :

- Create a Viewcontroller with the status bar and an empty view below it covering rest of area  to use it as placeholder view for other view controllers (say view A)
- Now to show any Viewcontroller you add that controller on A as subView like

  ```
   [A addSubView:anotherViewController.view];
  ```

  and remove it as

  ```
   [anotherViewController.view removeFromSuperView];
  ```
- In that case your status bar handling code will be at same place In your first ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way for you is to create an empty xib file -> add a uiview and apply the desire design on it. 
After this add a uiview class and then apply that class to the uiview. 
Now you need to create an IBoutles for the labels. 
After that in whatever controller you want to use u can use it

**HeaderPanel.h**

```
@interface HeaderPanel : UIView {

    IBOutlet UILabel *headline;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *headline;

@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

In MainViewController you can use the above view in viewDidLoad() method.

```
HeaderPanel* headerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderPanel" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
headerView.headline.text=@"Welcome to my app";
[self addSubView(headerView)];
```